# Make a zero order hold plot from a .csv file with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, csv

I want to make a [zero-order hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold) plot from a .csv file using the pgfplots package. My idea is to use the `\addplot+[const plot]` option. The documentation mentions `{<list of coordinates>}`  as input. My question is: Can I somehow transform the input from a .csv file into the coordinates format?

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=${t}$,
            ylabel=${u}$,
            xmin=0,xmax=8,
            ]
            \addplot+ [const plot, mark=none] coordinates{ table [col sep=comma] {u1.csv}};
            \addlegendentry{$u_{\text{heat,cool}$}
            \addplot+ [const plot, mark=none]  table [col sep=comma] {u1est.csv};
            \addlegendentry {$u_2$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please add, at least a reasonable beginning of, the two .csv files, so we can copy and try yor code? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- it is not entirely clear what is your problem
- sorry, but you not provide `csv˙ file, so it is impossible to replace (at least of part of) file by coordinates
- just curious, why you should do that? what is wrong at use table?
- BTW, you use ancient `pgfplots, recent one is` 1.18`
- an example od use of coordinates:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid,
    xlabel=${t}$,
    ylabel=${u}$,
    xmin=0,xmax=4,
    no marks
    ]
\addplot +[const plot] coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) (2,3) (3,1) (4,1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]